# Why does Haskell's 'even' function slow my program down?

Tags: performance, haskell

I have following code. It costs 1s to run with argument 1000000, but it costs 5s to run if replace *myEven* with standard [*even*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:even) function. I checked the code, the standard *even* function does exactly the same as * myEven *.

```
import Data.Word
import Data.List
import System.Environment

collatzNext :: Word32 -> Word32
collatzNext a = (if myEven a then a else 3*a+1) `div` 2

myEven :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
myEven a = (a `rem` 2) == 0

collatzLen :: Word32 -> Int
collatzLen a0 = length $ takeWhile (/= 1) $ iterate collatzNext a0

main = do
    [a0] <- getArgs
    let max_a0 = (read a0)::Word32
    print $ maximum $ map (\a0 -> (collatzLen a0, a0)) [1..max_a0]
```

Comment: just to be sure - have you read the [info-page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) and compiled the program with option `-O2`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: This is a compiler (well, library) regression in 7.10. It's fixed in 8.0, though: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11701

Answer (score 12):

If you add `{-# NOINLINE myEven #-}`, you'll get the same slowdown. The issue is that `myEven` is defined locally, so it's source is available to compiler, and it is inlined. All allocations and function call itself are eliminated:

```
Main.$wgo1 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Word# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=2, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType <S,1*U><L,U>]
Main.$wgo1 =
  \ (ww_s6n0 :: GHC.Prim.Word#) (ww1_s6n4 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww_s6n0 of wild_X2j {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.remWord# wild_X2j (__word 2) of _ [Occ=Dead] {
          __DEFAULT ->
            Main.$wgo1
              (GHC.Prim.quotWord#
                 (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                    (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                       (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word# (GHC.Prim.timesWord# (__word 3) wild_X2j))
                       (__word 1)))
                 (__word 2))
              (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s6n4 1);
          __word 0 ->
            Main.$wgo1
              (GHC.Prim.quotWord# wild_X2j (__word 2)) (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s6n4 1)
        };
      __word 1 -> ww1_s6n4
    }
```

But `even` is defined in other module and it is not marked as `INLINE` or `INLINEABLE`. As a result it is not inlined, and each call to `even` allocates boxed `Word32`:

```
Main.$wgo1 [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Word# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <S,U><L,U>]
Main.$wgo1 =
  \ (ww_s6mz :: GHC.Prim.Word#) (ww1_s6mD :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww_s6mz of wild_X1W {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case even
               @ Word32 GHC.Word.$fIntegralWord32 (GHC.Word.W32# wild_X1W)
        of _ [Occ=Dead] {
          False ->
            Main.$wgo1
              (GHC.Prim.quotWord#
                 (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word#
                    (GHC.Prim.plusWord#
                       (GHC.Prim.narrow32Word# (GHC.Prim.timesWord# (__word 3) wild_X1W))
                       (__word 1)))
                 (__word 2))
              (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s6mD 1);
          True ->
            Main.$wgo1
              (GHC.Prim.quotWord# wild_X1W (__word 2)) (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_s6mD 1)
        };
      __word 1 -> ww1_s6mD
    }
```

Note that `even` [is specialized](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#even) for `Int` and `Integer`, but not for `Word32`, so the issue doesn't occurs if you use `Int`.

Comment: Yup. Note that this will be fixed [in 8.0](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11701).

Comment: @Yuras: Thanks. If changed to Int, running time reduced from 5s to 1.8s.